# Utilizar Struts 2 com Maven, Eclipse e Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2

Eu baixei os exemplos fornecidos pela Apache de projetos Struts 2 no repositório deles [aqui](https://github.com/apache/struts-examples).

Tentei rodar o exemplo `helloworld`. Se eu executo através do Jetty pelo Maven com `mvn jetty:run`, o projeto funciona normalmente ao visitar `http://localhost:8080/helloworld/index.jsp`.

[image: exemplo funcionando]

Porém, se eu utilizo o Apache Tomcat 8.5 no Eclipse (atualmente tento executar utilizando Run As > Run on Server), eu tenho erros 404.

[image: exemplo dando 404]

Creio que seja alguma configuração errada no Eclipse ou no Tomcat que esteja causando esse erro, mas não consigo encontrar o que é. O que preciso fazer para utilizar o Struts 2 com o Apache Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

ola,

Na aba Servers dê um duplo clique no Tomcat e altere para usar a opção "Use Tomcat Installation" e então seleciona a pasta webapps da sua instalação.

Acredito que deva resolver.

Segue um link de ajuda

https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-tomcat